# Erro ao publicar aplicação no iis 8.5

Tags: .net, iis

Estou tentando publicar uma aplicação feita no FluorineFx no **IIS 8.5**, eu permito o `MIME type .aspx`, porém quando acesso uma página tenho o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenho 99,999% de certeza de que o site no IIS não está realmente associado a uma aplicação .NET. Quando um site é parte de uma aplicação ASP.NET, uma chamada a uma página .aspx para por um handler que ira internamente chamar a aplicação correspondente (vide pools de aplicações no IIS) para processar as instruções da página e devolver o conteúdo processado, ao invés de retornar o conteúdo do .aspx como se fosse um .txt.

De qualquer forma, para se certificar de que o tipo MIME é processado corretamente, verifique se no console do navegador não há nenhuma mensagem do tipo "tipo `foo` não especificado/desconhecido, servindo como tipo `bar`". Permitir o conteúdo é uma coisa - o IIS conhecer o tipo de conteúdo é outra. Se for esse o caso, você deve reconfigurar os tipos MIME no IIS. É raro isso acontecer, mas lembro que ao menos na versão 1.0 do ASP.NET (há mais de dez anos atrás) era possível, por erro, fazer com que o IIS não reconhecesse a extensão .aspx!

**Edit:** O problema mesmo, de acordo com comentário do OP, era que o IIS foi instalado depois do ASP.NET, aí o IIS não ficou registrado. Nada que o aspnet_regiis.exe (que fica na pasta do framework) não resolva :)

Comment: ok, como eu disse antes eu configurei o type .aspx, no iis pois nao vinha por padrão, eu adicionei na extensão: .aspx e no tipo coloquei application/aspx, sabe me dizer se há algum erro ai?

Comment: ASP.NET está registrado na máquina? Verifique se você consegue rodar outros sites, pois pode ser esse o caso. Se for isso, eu edito a resposta para conter o passo a passo de como registrar. P.S.: não é registro como registro de licença de uso de software, é registro como em registrar no Windows que ele deve trabalhar com ASP.NET.

Comment: Olá Renan, consegui cara, o ASP.NET não estava registrado na máquina, provavelmente porque instalei o iis depois do APS.NET. pelo prompt de comando executei na pasta do .net 2.0 o comando aspnet_regiis -i